# Why use unowned when you can use weak?

Tags: swift

In Swift, there is option to use `unowned` or `weak`.  Why use `unowned` when you can use `weak`? It seems the two are almost the same, with `weak` being safer.

Comment: I believe the only difference is weak must be optional, whereas unowned does not, giving you a cleaner syntax when the safety you get from weak is irrelevant, and the pointer getting cleaned up is a bug.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question. I do not think this should have been closed as a duplicate. The other question asks *what* these references are, while this question asks *why* one would use one of them, when the other provides additional safety.

Answer (score 10):

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) that the rules are as follows:

- Use a `weak` reference whenever it is valid for that reference to become `nil` at some point during its lifetime.
- Use an unowned reference when you know that the reference will never be nil once it has been set during initialization.

The reason for having `unowned` in the first place is that `weak` must be of an optional type, while `unowned` will be non-optional. This lets you avoid unwrapping and/or checking, which is associated with variables of optional type.

Both kinds of references carry the same costs: Swift keeps track of them, so that it could set `weak` references to `nil`, and mark `unowned` references invalid when the object they reference is destroyed.

Comment: "something that does not need to be done when the reference is marked unowned" Not true. The same thing has to be done with `unowned` references. Otherwise how can they guarantee that it will cause a runtime error when you access an `unowned` reference to a deallocated object?

Comment: @user102008 You are right, they have to keep track of both kinds of references. I edited the answer, thank you!